# .NET 6 Web API with Bearer Authentication returns 401 when using the [Authorize] Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I am currently working on setting up an Duende IdentityServer to secure my web app and API. Originally My API was in the same application as my IdentityServer. I am working on separating the two from each other. Currently My IdentityServer is deployed in Azure. The current design I am working with is

1. WebApp signs in using IdentityServer (Hosted in Azure)
2. WebApp calls API and sends Bearer Token in request (LocalHost)
3. API has Bearer authentication to validate against IdentityServer.(LocalHost)

The issue I have is even with a valid Bearer Token, I cannot get the basic [Authorize] attribute to work properly. It constantly returns a 401 - unauthorized.

What I have verified from my own hunting:

1. I am correctly adding the scope for access to the API to the JWT.
2. Made sure my `app.UseAuthenticate()` came before `app.UseAuthorization()`
3. Enabled CORS to accept all Origins,Methods, and headers.

I am at a total loss, I can not seem to figure out what I have configured wrong. I am using entity framework in my API to develop a database as well. That database context inherits from `IdentityDbContext`. I do not think this would mess with authentication, as I am not adding Identity in the startup its self.

My IdentityServer does have call `.AddDeveloperSigningCredential()` when Adding the IdentityServer to the web app. Do I need to have the signed credentials in my API/Webapp?

Here is the Startup for my API.

```cs
//Initializing WebApp Adding Razor page support and controller support
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(options => 
  {
    // base-address of your identityserver
    options.Authority = builder.Configuration["identity-server-url"];
    options.Audience = "LMS.API";
    // audience is optional, make sure you read the following paragraphs
    // to understand your options
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters 
    {
      RoleClaimType = ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType,
    };

  });

builder.Services.AddCors(confg =>
  confg.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
    p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()));

//Add Key Vault to configuration to be used in entire application
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new(builder.Configuration["KeyVault:Endpoint"]), new DefaultAzureCredential());

builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
var migrationsAssembly = typeof (Program).Assembly.FullName;

//Grab connection string from key vault
string dbConnectionString = builder.Configuration["db-connection-string"];

// Repository registration

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAssignmentRepository, AssignmentRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICourseRepository, CourseRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISchoolRepository, SchoolRepository>();

//Auto Generated shit
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

//add support for MediatR
builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(CreateAssignmentForCourse).Assembly);

builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(Program).Assembly);

//Injecting DB connection string into Master Context class, 
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MasterContext>(options => 
{
  options.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString, sqlServerOptionsAction: sqloptions => 
  {
    sqloptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
  });
});

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

//Build webApp
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) 
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(routes => 
{
  routes.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: You mean the token is generated by the Azure hosted authorization service and the token is validated against the local identity server?

Comment: Have you tried: `UseAuthentication`, `UseRouting`, `UseAuthorization`, `UseEndpoints`?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delayed response. I did figure out the issue here. I was trying to validate the audience to match the API scope I created for my API. However, I manually configured the API scope by manually changing the db tables. So, long story short, the Audience scope in my JWT was null and didn't match, therefore causing a Not Authorized HTTP response.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future!